# Itext PdfStamper getOverContent returns null when ByteArrayOutputStream used

Tags: java, itext, bytearrayoutputstream, pdfstamper

I am working on a pdf file. I need to add a watermark on an exist pdf file. That's why, I wrote following code. When I used FileOutputStream it works perfectly, but I need to use ByteArrayOutputStream because my data are come from database and I need to save it as byte array. Problem starts in here. When I use ByteArrayOutputStream getOvercontent method of PdfStamper returns null. How can I handle this? Thanks in advance.

```
byte[] bytes = getAsByteArray();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
int numberOfPages= reader.getNumberOfPages();
outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
Font font = font(Font.NORMAL, 135, Color.RED);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
     //over Content is null
     PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
     Phrase p = new Phrase("WATERMARK", font);
     PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
     gs.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
     over.setGState(gs);
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 330, 450, 45);
     over.saveState();
}
```

And the old version of code is this.

```
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("myPdf.pdf"));
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
int numberOfPages= reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("MyPdfOut.pdf"));
Font f = font(Font.NORMAL, 135, Color.RED);
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
    Phrase p = new Phrase("WATERMARK", f);
    PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
    gs.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
    over.setGState(gs);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 330, 450, 45);
    over.saveState();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **forbidden**:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
```

You create an `OutputStream`, named `outputStream`, and it seems that you copy a full-blown existing PDF to that `OutputStream` (using `write()`). Then you seem to have the intention to add another full-blown PDF to that `OutputStream` by passing that same `OutputStream` to the `PdfStamper` instance. That should result in a corrupt PDF file.

This will also result in **illegal PDF syntax**:

```
 PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
 Phrase p = new Phrase("WATERMARK");
 PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
 gs.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
 over.setGState(gs);
 ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 330, 450, 45);
 over.saveState();
```

You have a `saveState()` operator, but you never use `restoreState()`. For every `saveState()`, you should have a `restoreState()`. Your `saveState()` is in the wrong position! It's as if you don't know what `saveState()` and `restoreState()` are about.

Finally, you start counting a 0, but the first page is page 1, not page 0. Hence `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)` is wrong. It should be `for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)`. This error is what causes `over` to be `null`.

This is an attempt to fix your code:

```
// create a Phrase with a certain font
Font font = font(Font.NORMAL, 135, Color.RED);
Phrase p = new Phrase("WATERMARK", font);
// Create a reader and a stamper
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getAsByteArray());
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
int numberOfPages= reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
     PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
     over.saveState();
     PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
     gs.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
     over.setGState(gs);
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 330, 450, 45);
     over.restoreState();
}
```